# Display sequence using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to take number of threads and the maximum number in a sequence from the user as input and I have to print the sequence from 0 to max number using the number of threads created , each thread should atleast print 1 number and no repetition of the same number is allowed.

my code is printing the sequence for each of the thread created and hence is repeating the numbers in the sequence.please tell me how can I have all threads print the seqeunce together and not individually so that I can have output like

```
max sequence-4
max threads-3
Thread 1-0
Thread 2-1
Thread 3-2
Thread 1-3
```

should the variable that is used to print the sequence be static?

Here is my code-

```
package com.demo;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class SequencePrinter {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter the no.Of threads");
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sn.nextInt();// No. of Threads

    Worker t1[] = new Worker[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the max no.");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int r = sc.nextInt();// MAX no.

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        t1[i] = new Worker();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        t1[i].setNext(t1[i + 1]);
    }

    // Create the workers
    // Worker w1 = new Worker();
    // Worker w2 = new Worker();
    // Worker w3 = new Worker();

    // chain them in a round robin fashion
    // w1.setNext(w2);
    // w2.setNext(w3);
    // w3.setNext(w1);

    // for (int i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
    //
    // Thread t[i] = (Thread) new Thread(t1[i], "Thread-" + "i" + "-");
    //
    // }

    // Create named threads for the workers
    // Thread t1 = new Thread(w1, "Thread-1 - ");
    // Thread t2 = new Thread(w2, "Thread-2 - ");
    // Thread t3 = new Thread(w3, "Thread-3 - ");

    // start the threads

    for (int i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
        t1[i].start();

    }

    // t1.start();
    // t2.start();
    // t3.start();

    // Seed the first worker
    t1[0].accept(0);
    // t1[1].accept(1);
    // try
    // {
    // t1[0].join();
    // }
    // catch(Exception e)
    // {
    // System.out.println("exception");
    // }
    for (int i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
        t1[i].setVar(r);

    }

}

}

class Worker extends Thread {

int r = 0;
int prnt = 0;
BlockingQueue<Integer> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();
Worker next = null; // next worker in the chain

public void setNext(Worker t) {
    this.next = t;
}

public void accept(int i) {
    q.add(i);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.toString();
}

public void setVar(int i) {
    r = i;// The Max no.to print
}

int[] ij = new int[r];

@Override

public synchronized void run() {

    try {

        int i = q.take(); // blocks till it receives a number

        while (r != prnt) {

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + prnt);

            Thread.sleep(1000); // delay to slow the printing

            if (next != null) {

                next.accept(i + 1); // pass the next number to the next
            }
            // if(prnt==0|| prnt==1)
            prnt = prnt + 1;

        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " interrrupted.");
    }

}
}


the code prints folllowing output

Enter the no.Of threads
2
Enter the max no.
4
Thread-0:0
Thread-0:1
Thread-1:0
Thread-1:1
Thread-0:2
Thread-0:3
Thread-1:2
Thread-1:3
```

Comment: Can you please never use 'no' instead of number :)

Comment: yes I can , have removed no and replaced with number :)

Comment: I like "r" for "maximum number" even better.

Comment: max no. No, I said! Don't touch the painting! MAX!!!

Comment: Why do you need to work with some sequential by nature (a sequence) in a parallel way ?

Comment: Should the threads be run in order (1, then 2, then 3, then 1 again, 2 again etc?) Should the numbers printed rightmost be ordered? Your code and the example you gave hint that they should, but the text of the task doesn't. If it's the latter, @yeoman's solution does solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is way more readable with variables and methods that have actual names.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class SequencePrinter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("number of threads: ");
        final int numberOfThreads = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("maximum number to print: ");
        final int maximumNumber = scanner.nextInt();

        scanner.close();

        for (int index = 0; index < numberOfThreads; ++index)
        {
            final int workerIndex = index;

            Thread worker = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    for (int number = workerIndex; number <= maximumNumber; number += numberOfThreads)
                    {
                        print(workerIndex, number);
                    }
                }
            });

            worker.start();
        }
    }

    synchronized
    private static void print(int thread, int number)
    {
        System.out.println("thread " + thread + ", number " + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes the code doesn't follow naming conventions , sorry about that

Comment: Btw. I didn't reformat your code. This is a way shorter solution that actually works and needs no queue.

Answer (score 0):

What about using both Java8 and the Executor API capabilities ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Use {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Number of threads: ");
            int numberOfThreads = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Maximum number to print: ");
            int maximumNumber = scanner.nextInt();

            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
            Integer sequence = new Integer(0);
            IntStream.range(0, maximumNumber)
                        .forEach(i -> pool.submit(() -> {
                            synchronized (sequence) {
                                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + sequence++);
                            }
                        }));

            pool.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: as @starikoff said, this code doesn't guarantee the OP's requirement *each thread should at least print 1 number*.

Comment: doesn't guarantee "each thread should atleast print 1 number" requirement of OP

Comment: @starikoff Indeed. Do you have any idea how I can improve my answer to respect this requirement or should I delete my answer ?

Comment: unfortunately I can't think of a way to improve it while still leaving the "loop" to the executor (which is the whole point of using it); maybe somebody else will have an idea

Comment: Why do you synchronize on the AtomicInteger?

Comment: @yeoman Otherwise the display order is unpredictable (even if a number is not generated twice).

Comment: You are of course right... that's a readability issue caused by using AtomicInteger :) I would recommend using a one-member int array or an static int member variable instead, for the simple reason that it does not suggest that the atomicity plays any role...

Comment: Btw., I noticed that you prefer K&R brackets over BSD. I always found that K&R bracketing visually cramps the code tightly together at the beginning of a block, while being just as airy at the end of a block as BSD. What is your personal reason for choosing the denser K&R style with less vertical space in between things? :)

Comment: K&R being the opening bracket on its own line style, BSD the one with opening brackets on their own line, just in case these old terms are unfamiliar to anybody :D

Comment: @yeoman I've removed the `AtomicInteger`, since it was more confusing than helpful. About my brackets style preference: I used BSD for years then I realized that with K&R you can actually display more line of code on a screen without scrolling. I think than with an indented code, you wouldn't need brackets at all (see Python for example) ! That's why I consider brackets as a visual noise and K&R allows my eyes not to be distracted by the opening bracket by placing it in a place my eyes don't look at.

Comment: Interesting :) I don't miss the brackets in python but the missing vertical space annoys me, but I don't add an empty line because it would be soo unusual... I mostly work on 27" displays with small fonts, though... I guess you mostly work on a laptop with a rather big font? :D

Answer (score 0):

Because the idea of using an AtomicInteger was mentioned: that does not change much, and it certainly does not make the output sequentially ordered:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class SequencePrinter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("number of threads: ");
        final int numberOfThreads = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("maximum number to print: ");
        final int maximumNumber = scanner.nextInt();

        scanner.close();

        final AtomicInteger currentNumber = new AtomicInteger(0);

        for (int index = 0; index < numberOfThreads; ++index)
        {
            final int workerIndex = index;

            Thread worker = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int number = currentNumber.getAndIncrement();

                        if (number <= maximumNumber)
                        {
                            print(workerIndex, number);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            worker.start();
        }
    }

    synchronized
    private static void print(int thread, int number)
    {
        System.out.println("thread " + thread + ", number " + number);
    }
}
```

session:

```
number of threads: 3
maximum number to print: 11
thread 0, number 0
thread 2, number 2
thread 2, number 4
thread 2, number 5
thread 2, number 6
thread 2, number 7
thread 2, number 8
thread 2, number 9
thread 2, number 10
thread 2, number 11
thread 1, number 1
thread 0, number 3
```

The reason for this is that the AtomicInteger does not synchronize the output. It is simply another way to make sure that every number is printed just once. In the other example, this was achieved through a mathematical trick :)

This is not a solution, btw., because it is not guaranteed that every thread will eventually print anything. One thread could end up printing all the numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Please look at class [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). It fits your purposes perfectly and would make your code simpler. You won't have to worry about checking for duplication. All your threads will need to go is to get a value and check if it is less or equal to the max value and if so print it. Otherwise just terminate the thread. And yes you AtomicInteger variable will need to be static, so it will be the same instance available to to all your Threads.

Comment: could you at least elaborate how the "each thread should atleast print 1 number" requirement will be satisfied in your solution? will this solution be better (more readable, shorter etc.) than @yeoman's? hard to tell without seeing the code (pseudocode, anything)

Comment: I am not going give you a ready answer to what looks like a school task. I gave you a tool to help to resolve the issue of duplication. In order to resolve "prevention of thread starvation" requirement you will need to use classes java.util.concurrent.Semaphore or java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock or wait() - notify(), notifyAll() methods (which is an older way). I am happy to give you tools and hints to help but I have no intention to write the code for you

Comment: I'm just a curious bypasser, and currently I am curious if this answer brings anything valuable to the table because it doesn't look that using `AtomicInteger` will somehow help OP. And if in order to satisfy his requirements we need to bring synchronization, then will there be any point in using AtomicInteger? Depends on how it will be used and how synchronization will be done, but you are not showing how. Also, "each thread should atleast print 1 number" is not "prevention of thread starvation": if all tasks are happily processed by all-but-one threads, then no thread has been starving.

Comment: AtomicInteger is already synchronized internally. That is the whole point of an "Atomic..." classes. They guarantee that each of their acess methods are atomic and is thread safe. As for thread starvation - if one thread never gets to execute its method because other threads always get to lock-protected resource first - this single thread is starving even if it is the only one, the issue is called "Thread starvation"

Comment: You agreed that another synch mechanism is required as well as `AtomicInteger` to satisfy OPs requirement, so if the only recommendation in your answer is to use `AtomicInteger` then it's not an answer. Next, if another synchronization mechanism is used then using `AtomicInteger` is as justified as using `BigInteger` or `Integer` or `int`, which OP does already. Overall, -1. As for "thread starvation", OP's requirement might not be satisfied because of thread starvation or because of some other reasons, depends on the solution, and you are not showing it, so I'm only left with guesses.

Comment: And no, a variable doesn't have to be static in order to be available to all threads, it's enough to pass the same instance (:

Comment: I totally disagree with you. AtomicInteger solves sync issue completely. that means that no thread ever can get the same value if method getAndIncrement() or method incrementAndGet() is used. that takes care out-of-the-box of one requirement. The other requirement is a different story and That could be solved by various means including but not limited to Locks and Semaphores. The other solution could be using pools provided by ExecutorService and its children. As for static vs non-static you are correct, but static is the simplest and acceptable solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125099/discussion-between-michael-gantman-and-starikoff).

Comment: Wow, this conversation looks like it took 17 times as much time and effort than a little example :D And yes, I know the question looks like school work but showing people readable and working solutions is imo not a bad thing. They obviously have teachers that teach them to name a variable holding the maximum number to print 'r'... -.-